# Devise after_confirmation_path_for and nil redirection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails 4, one of my actions fails because it redirects to nil. What is the best practice to get a list of redirections and find the faulty call ?

Edit:
The offending code is:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
        redirect_to some_specific_path_helper
    end
end
```

Whenever I hit the email confirmation action in Devise, this action fails and reports about a nil redirection.

Comment: Do the rails server logs show nothing?

Comment: this is where testing comes in handy

Comment: There is no such a thing as a "list of redirections", **unless** your redirects are defined in your `config/routes.rb`.  If your redirects are defined in your config/routes.rb, you can run `bundle exec rake routes`. Then you should see something like:
`named_path GET  /path(.:format)  redirect(301)`

If your redirect is defined inside a controller action (which I suspect is what you are doing now), you can't get list of all your redirects. Could you provide your controller code? Can u show some logs?

Comment: @Sinstein: the logs did not show anything peculiar, because the problem was with my understanding of the `after_confirmation_path_for` method, see my answer.

Comment: @Codextremist: thank you for your comment, it led me to finding my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

So my mistake was that `after_confirmation_path_for` is not an action but a simple path helper. Therefore, calling redirect from within confirmation_path_for is improper and causes this method to return nil (i.e. nothing).

The proper use of `after_confirmation_path_for` is to have it returning the chosen path, like so:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
        # just return the path, do not call redirect
        some_specific_path_helper 
    end
end
```